# How to get triangle upper matrix without the diagonal using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Lets say I have the following matrix:

```
A = np.array([
     [1,2,3],
     [4,5,6],
     [7,8,9]])
```

How can I extract the upper triangle matrix without the diagonal efficiently? 
The output would be the following array:

```
B = np.array([2,3,6])
```

Comment: Have you tried [numpy.triu](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.triu_indices.html)?

Comment: What you have here aren't really matrices, but tuples with lists in them.

Comment: @en_lorithai Presumably they are just trying to give a representation of their matrix and are aware of that.

Comment: @miradulo was under the impression that code should be verifiable, but ok.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One approach with masking -

```
def upper_tri_masking(A):
    m = A.shape[0]
    r = np.arange(m)
    mask = r[:,None] < r
    return A[mask]
```

Another with [`np.triu_indices`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.triu_indices.html) -

```
def upper_tri_indexing(A):
    m = A.shape[0]
    r,c = np.triu_indices(m,1)
    return A[r,c]
```

Sample run -

```
In [403]: A
Out[403]: 
array([[79, 17, 79, 58, 14],
       [87, 63, 89, 26, 31],
       [69, 34, 90, 24, 96],
       [59, 60, 80, 52, 46],
       [75, 80, 11, 61, 47]])

In [404]: upper_tri_masking(A)
Out[404]: array([17, 79, 58, 14, 89, 26, 31, 24, 96, 46])
```

Runtime test -

```
In [415]: A = np.random.randint(0,9,(5000,5000))

In [416]: %timeit upper_tri_masking(A)
10 loops, best of 3: 64.2 ms per loop

In [417]: %timeit upper_tri_indexing(A)
1 loop, best of 3: 252 ms per loop
```

Comment: Another choice, [`np.tru_indices_from`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.triu_indices_from.html).

Comment: @miradulo Yup that's another alternative! I added that `np.triu` mostly for a comparison/completeness, as I knew masking would be the way to go here.

Comment: Yeah its interesting how much slower `triu_indices` is than the mask. Always appreciate your answers!

Comment: @miradulo Neat, never seen that one before.

Answer (score 10):

Short answer

```
A[np.triu_indices_from(A, k=1)]
```

Long answer:

You can get the indices of the upper triangle in your matrix using:

```
indices = np.triu_indices_from(A)

indices
Out[1]: 
(array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2], dtype=int64),
 array([0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2], dtype=int64))
```

This will include the diagonal indices, to exclude them you can offset the diagonal by 1:

```
indices_with_offset = np.triu_indices_from(A, k=1)

indices_with_offset
Out[2]: 
(array([0, 0, 1], dtype=int64), 
 array([1, 2, 2], dtype=int64))
```

Now use these with your matrix as a mask

```
A[indices_with_offset]

Out[3]: 
array([2, 3, 6])
```

See docs [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.triu_indices_from.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
np.triu(A, k=1)
indices = np.where(np.triu(np.ones(A.shape), k=1).astype(bool))
print(A[x])
```

```
[2 3 6]
```

Comment: Explain why your answer to make it distinct from the others and rid yourself from "low-quality answer" label. (End of Review).

Answer (score 1):

To summarize other answers. The shortest answer could be:

```
B = A[np.triu_indices_from(A,k=1)]
```